Pip unable to find file and install libraries
I am trying to install libraries for python (I am using PyCharm), but something changed and Pip has been refusing to work. 
I have no idea what changed/why, but every time I try and install a library, I get the following error:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pandas/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas

Exact Error
I have tried messing with proxy settings, using force, using paths instead of aliases, downloading .whl files, deleting and reinstalling, etc. but nothing has worked. 
Based on the error, it seems to be a pathing issue and/or interpreter issue, but I have been unable to fix it.
If there is anything more information I can provide just let me know.

Do you have good Internet connection?

Also what version of Python are you using?

Maybe your venv is borked, I would first try just removing the whole .venv directory and creating a new venv, then pip installing everything in there again. And you really should use a requirements.txt or some other dependency tool like PDM or Poetry.
